# Laravel relationship executes multiple queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have three tables

```
users, role, user_role
```

and I have added relationship but when I run following:

```
$user=User::where('id',2)
    ->with(['role'])->first();
```

my query log shows that two queries are executed:

First query:
`` select * from `users` where `id` = '2' limit 1 ``

Second query:
`` select `roles`.*, `user_role`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `user_role`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `user_role` on `roles`.`id` = `user_role`.`role_id` where `user_role`.`user_id` in ('2') ``

Can anyone help me understand why it's executing two queries instead of one? Is DB is better than relationship since I need to execute in every request since I will access pages based on role .

Comment: Which query do you have in mind that does both? Unless you provide us both scenarios, how can we say which one is better

Comment: @Paras.when i run the code it will return both queries.may i know why  relatonship return both queries

Comment: @paras  if i rune $user=user::where('id',2)
             ->with(['role'])->first(); then it iwll exciute two queries

Comment: Yes, two queries are required. Can't be done in one. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select the first user user with his/her roles. Well there's really no way to do this with one query.

The Eloquent builder, rightly so first queries the user table to get the user details and then does a join of `roles` and `user_role` tables to get the role details for that specific user ID.

I don't see how this is bad. In fact, I do believe you would need 2 queries to achieve what you want.

Even if you do with the DB facade, it would need these 2 queries. If you have something else in mind, please post the queries that you think are suitable for the job

Comment: @Paras.thanks for the answer .some how i confused myself .